# Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis binder

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, aws-java-sdk, spring-integration-aws

I am not able to connect to AWS kinesis in Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis binder (1.2.0.RELEASE) without using the default configuration at the system level. Only if the system has already been configured to use the default profile and the access key id and secret access key are set with the [default] profile the application works. Otherwise, it is not able to connect to AWS resources by throwing this exception:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@3b2c8bda: Unable to load credentials from service endpoint, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@688d619c: No AWS profile named 'default']
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:136)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1225)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:801)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:751)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:668)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:532)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:512)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3768)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:3737)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.executeDescribeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1836)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1804)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table.describe(Table.java:137)
    at org.springframework.integration.aws.metadata.DynamoDbMetadataStore.afterPropertiesSet(DynamoDbMetadataStore.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
```

I have tried the following options and none of them worked for me:

- Set environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
- Set Java system properties `aws.accessKeyId` and `aws.secretKey`
- Set `cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey` and `cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey` in the `application.yml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that for some reason the AWSCredentialProvider bean has been loaded incorrectly, so I was able to address this issue temporarily by setting the following bean. It's not a right fix, but it did unblock my work:

```
@Configuration
public class AWSCredentialProvider {
  @Value("${aws.access-key}")
  protected String accessKey;

  @Value("${aws.secret-key}")
  protected String secretKey;

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public AWSCredentialsProvider buildAWSCredentialsProvider() {
    AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    return new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not helping me to resolve the issue.

Comment: @havryliuk What version of SCS and Kinesis binder do you use?

Answer (score 4):

This just about drove me nuts. After careful tracing through the AWS code, I found that if you set the system property

```
cloud.aws.credentials.use-default-aws-credentials-chain: true
```

it switches in the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`. Otherwise, it uses a chain of two providers - `EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper` and `ProfileCredentialsProvider`.

This is for Spring Boot 2.3.4. For version 2.2.5, the system property is

```
cloud.aws.credentials.useDefaultAwsCredentialsChain: true
```

I haven't researched what version it changed to kebab case. Without this, it will ignore credentials passed in either environment variables or system properties. This code is in `ContextCredentialsAutoConfiguration.registerBeanDefinitions()`.

Comment: Isn't kebab-case the same as hyphens with Spring relaxed binding?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

I think `spring-cloud-starter-aws` not working to auto configuration.
So I set the access key and secret key programmatically like this:

```
@Configuration
class AWSS3Configuration {

  @Value("\${cloud.aws.credentials.access-key}")
  val accessKey: String = ""

  @Value("\${cloud.aws.credentials.secret-key}")
  val secretKey: String = ""

  @Bean
  fun amazonS3(): AmazonS3 =
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
      .withCredentials(AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey)))
      .build()

}
```